# One function for multiple Textbox WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have 5 textboxes that gets editable on double click.

Below is method i have written for one textbox.

```
private void TextBox_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            txtFirstLctrTime.IsReadOnly = false;
            txtFirstLctrTime.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
            txtFirstLctrTime.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
        }
```

Is there any way i can use **same method for all text box** instead of writing different method for all??  I am fairly new to programming

Comment: Just a design question: Why? Does the user expect to have to double-click a textbox to be able to edit? Usually the user knows: textbox gray => disabled, textbox white => editable. Why confuse the user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can atach this handler to all textboxes. Then you check the sender, because that's the textbox you actually clicked:

```
    private void TextBox_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var textBox = sender as TextBox;

        textBox.IsReadOnly = false;
        textBox.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
        textBox.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
    }
```

You should look into MVVM and data binding thought, having click-handlers and code-behind has it's limits.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Worked perfectly.

Comment: Please note that this may throw a NullReferenceException in case you attach the event handler to anything but a textbox. Shouldn't be a problem, just to point it out.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar I have just attached it to textbox, so i guess there should not be any issue :)

Answer (score 1):

Attach same handler to all textboxes and use sender argument to get textbox instance which raised event:

```
private void  MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
     TextBox textBox = (TextBox)sender;
    textBox.IsReadOnly = false;
    textBox.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
    textBox.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way. Sender is a parameter which can tell You which controll fired this event. Look at my example below:

```
private void TextBox_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
  TextBox tbWhichFiredThisEvent = sender as TextBox;
  if(tbWhichFiredThisEvent != null)
  {
    tbWhichFiredThisEvent.IsReadOnly = false;
    // ... etc.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to inherit from TextBox and implement your specific behavior on the OnDoubleClick method.

This way you can have this control on different views without repeated code.

Comment: Any way i can select combobox only in particular panel and use above method?

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what you mean